# Jquery ui datepicker minDate greater then 0 adds blue color to the date, how to remove it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery ui datepicker. When adding greater value the 0 to the `minDate`. The min date gets a blue color (highlight). how do I remove it?

Working snippet below:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: '0'

});

$('.button').on('click', function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker('option', 'minDate', '+1'); 

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





<div class="datepicker"></div>
<button class="button">pressMe</button>
```

Comment: it's selecting it by default.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update the css of the plugin. here a just set the color, background and border ob the selected as the same of a non-selected

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: '0'

});

$('.button').on('click', function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker('option', 'minDate', '+1'); 

});1
```

```css
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover{
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5 !important;
  background: #f6f6f6 !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





<div class="datepicker"></div>
<button class="button">pressMe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the minimum date is causing the first available date to select. According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) you should be able to unset a date selection like so:

```
.datepicker( "setDate", null );
```

This does not work. In the past there was a [defect related](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159) to this that was marked as fixed, but it is obviously still around.

It would appear the first date is going to select automatically and even styling it doesn't fix that, but may be all you want.